# DevTools: how to define user stylesheet and load it by default?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Today on Smashing Magazine's Facebook page was a post:

> Just saw a young girl showing off Devtools to her (amazed) friends,
>   adding transforms to Facebook. Web developers have magic powers after
>   all. Quote: “Just define rotation and skew in a user stylesheet, load
>   it by default and your boyfriend will go mad in blink of a second."

Could someone guide me through that process?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, hit `Ctrl-Shift-I` to open up dev tools. From there, hit the `elements` tab. If you're reading this right now, do it on this page. You should see stackoverflow's HTML. Click on the `<body>` tag and look to the left where it says `Styles`. From there, look to where it says `background-color:white` and click on `white`. You should be able to input your own color there, and you'll see a change on the page instantly. You can do this with any block of HTML in the page, on any page. You can add style attributes, edit them, etc. You can modify the page's Javascript too. Play around with it.

Have fun.

Comment: thanks a lot. Just one more thing, as I understand from this - 
"define rotation and skew in a user stylesheet, load it by default" -
there is a way to save changes and load them even when the sitw is opend in a new tab

Comment: Rotation and skew are CSS webkit styles. You simply add them like any other CSS attribute in Chrome dev-tools.

Comment: sorry haven't finished the comment and posted it accidentally, the question was if there is a way to save changes and load them even when the site is opend in a new tab

Comment: Not that I know of, no. You can always just keep the stuff in the clipboard and paste it, or make a stylesheet, save it to some fileserver, and change the stylesheet imports to include that one on load each time.